# Node.js/Express: passing session ID not via cookie

Tags: node.js, express, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a set of REST API for communicating between Express and the Unity 3D game engine. But Unity's [WWW class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) doesn't support cookies officially. (Looks like it DOES support cookies but it's [undocumented](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/255051/www-and-cookieslogin.html))

So I want to pass the session ID to express as a GET/POST parameter.

**EDIT:**
Question is: Is there any way to obtain the session data associated to given session ID?

Comment: @JonTaylor No. Uh, I mean I can pass the session ID to express, but I have no idea how I can obtain the actual session data associated to the session ID.

Comment: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sessions-and-cookies-in-node

Comment: Thanks @alexjamesbrown! I found a document to get it done! http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.get()` method of the [session store](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html) object. For example, put following code before `app.use(app.router)`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var session_id = (req.body && req.body.sid) || req.query && req.query.sid
    req.sessionStore && req.sessionStore.get(session_id, function(err, session) {
        if (session) {
            // createSession() re-assigns req.session
            req.sessionStore.createSession(req, session)
        }
        return next()
    })
})
```